# C: for loop int initial declaration

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc, syntax-error

Can someone elaborate on the following gcc error?

```
$ gcc -o Ctutorial/temptable.out temptable.c 
temptable.c: In function ‘main’:
temptable.c:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
```

temptable.c:

```
...
/* print Fahrenheit-Celsius Table */
main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 300; i += 20)
    {
        printf("F=%d C=%d\n",i, (i-32) / 9);        
    }
}
```

P.S: I vaguely recall that `int i` should be declared before a `for` loop. I should state that I am looking for an answer that gives a historical context of C standard.

Comment: Check out this previous question related to C variable declaration for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288441/variable-declaration-placement-in-c

Comment: Note that the temperature conversion formula is incorrect; in integer arithmetic, it should be `(5 * (i - 32)) / 9` (the `5` is missing).  Usually, you need floating point arithmetic – but then you need to change your printf format from `C=%d` to `C=%./2f` or something similar too (and you convert with `(5.0 * (i - 32)) / 9.0`).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; ...)
```

is a syntax that was introduced in C99. In order to use it you must enable C99 mode by passing `-std=c99` (or some later standard) to GCC. The C89 version is:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; ...)
```

EDIT

Historically, the C language always forced programmers to declare all the variables at the begin of a block. So something like:

```
{
   printf("%d", 42); 
   int c = 43;  /* <--- compile time error */
```

must be rewritten as:

```
{
   int c = 43;
   printf("%d", 42);
```

a block is defined as:

```
block := '{' declarations statements '}'
```

C99, C++, C#, and Java allow declaration of variables anywhere in a block.

The real reason (guessing) is about allocating internal structures (like calculating stack size) ASAP while parsing the C source, without go for another compiler pass.

Comment: Just a note: when using the c99 version, don't forget that the declared variable is local to the for-loop block, and will not exist afterward, when it has gone out of scope.

Comment: An additional note that may be of historical interest.  One way around this rule prior to the C99 standard was creating a block within a block.  You would declare a variable in the middle of a block, and surround it and code that used it with more bracers {}

Comment: It is also worth mention that , for instance, on new versions of GCC, the default version of C is updated to a more updated version then C89 --> so this whole issue WONT create a compilation error in the first place...(I'm using gcc 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 and did not have any compilation errors not warnings for this snippet of code).

Comment: Just add a word if someone really wants to experiment with it with compiler flag `-std=c89`: don't forget to add `-pedantic` to ask the compiler to get serious.

Answer (score 20):

Before C99, you had to define the local variables at the start of a block.  C99 imported the C++ feature that you can intermix local variable definitions with the instructions and you can define variables in the `for` and `while` control expressions.