# Declaration in for statement in c

Tags: c, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C: for loop int initial declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287863/c-for-loop-int-initial-declaration)

Can we declare some variables in `for` statement in C programming?If so,in which version of c standard will we find the feature?

Comment: In new version its possible that is `c99`.

Comment: @icepack I searched in this site before posting my question,but have not  found the duplicate question,why?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin you can raise this question at http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C89/C90, all declarations have to appear at the beginning of a block:

```
/* valid in C89/C90 */
printf("Hello\n");
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int j = i % 3;
        printf("%d\n", j);
    }
}
```

Starting with C99 you can mix declarations and statements, and declare variables in the first part of a `for`:

```
/* valid in C99 */
printf("Hello\n");
int whatever;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int j = i % 3;
    printf("%d\n", j);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that starting with the c99 standard. A straight compile of the code:

```
int main()
{
   for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
     printf("%d\n", i);
   return 0;
}
```

with (the default "gnu89") `gcc` would give you the answer:

> In function `main` :
>     
> error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
>     
> note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

Answer (score -1):

In pure C you can't declare variables in `for` statement. This feature available only in C++. 
In C all the variables must be declared at the beginning of the code block

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin that would depend on his definition of what "pure" C is. The C99 spec has not been out very long when you measure against how long the C language has existed, and new features might not be considered to be pure. Indeed, based on Mike's answer, C99 isn't even the default in GCC yet.

Comment: @mah Based on Mike's answer, C89 isn't even the default in GCC yet. Color me unimpressed.