# Writing functions for a command line in C. Errors

Tags: c, command-line, syntax-error, command-line-arguments, undeclared-identifier

I'm writing a program in C that calls functions from the command line and it is coming up with errors all in the first line of code (the for statement) and I'm not sure why or what they are. It says "syntax error found, expecting ;" "syntax error found, expecting )" "undeclared indentifier i" and "illegal statement termination."

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++ )
  {
    if(0 == stricmp("ParameterA", argv[i]))
    {
      exec1 = TRUE;
    }
    else if(0 == stricmp("ParameterB", argv[i]))
    {
      exec2 = FALSE;
    }
    else if(0 == stricmp("ParameterC", argv[i]))
    {
      exec2 = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unknown parameter: %s", argv[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please format that code, indenting with 4 spaces, please!

Comment: is exec1 & exec2 declared anywhere?  you should return an int too

Answer (score 1):

In C variable should be declared before any executable code.

you can change the code to

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++ )
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you can't declare **int i** inside a **FOR** loop
declare **int i** before the loop

Comment: In C99 it is possible to have the declaration of the int inside the for loop, e.g. `for (int i = 0;...` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287863/c-for-loop-int-initial-declaration But C99 is probably not what is being used by the OP.