# What's the difference between these for loops?

Tags: c, for-loop, variable-assignment

What's the difference between these two for loops? I was told not to use the second example in my code. I'm baffled by this since It's not a problem in other languages.

So what's the difference/issue with this or is it only a preference?

```
//ex1
int i;
for(i = 0; i<whatever; i++){...code}

//ex2
for(int i=0; i<whatever;i++){...code}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287863/c-for-loop-int-initial-declaration) might answer your question at least partly: the second is not valid C89.

Comment: For my curiosity, who told you not to use the second construct? This is really bad advice.

Answer (score 17):

The difference is in the scoping of `i`.

In the first example, `i` has scope inside AND after the loop.

In the second example, `i` has scope inside the loop.

The second example is C99 and later.

Use the second example when you can, the first when you need `i` after the loop, or when your compiler does not support C99.

Answer (score 3):

The second is supported by C99 but not by C89. The difference lies in scoping as well as initialization points. Scoping is determined by parenthesis'. To understand what i mean:

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;//-------------------------------------------------
    {//                                                       |
        int i=1;//------------------------------------------  |
        {//                                                |  |
            for(int i=2; i < 1; i++)//-----------------    |  |
            {//Declaring in loop works only in C99    |                                       |    |  |
                 {//-----------------                 |    |  |
                      int i=3;//    |                 |    |  |
                 }//-----------------                 |    |  |
            }//----------------------------------------    |  | 
        }//                                                |  |   
    }//-----------------------------------------------------  |
    //---------------------------------------------------------
}
```

The dotted lines show the scoping of the different `i`'s in the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of i variable is different.

In the second case variable scope is for loop itself. In first case, i variable belongs to outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: Variables should be declared in the *tightest* scope possible.

Why?
Consider a typo, that you insert a `;` after your for loop:

```
int i; 
for(i = 0; i<whatever; i++);
{  }
```

You won't get an error if you declare `i` outside the scope of the loop and that's a way better than the previous case.

**BUT**

```
for(int i = 0; i<whatever; i++);
{  }
```

You'll get an error because `i` is not known in the scope of `{ }`. So it's better to declare variables in the tightest scope when it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the second example is invalid in C89 and/or C90, but is available in C99 and later. Any other differences than that are that `i` is only accessible within the loop in the second example, where the first example's `i` is in the outer-scope.

I always use the form in the first example because the program becomes more consistent and error resistant without me thinking too much.