# Array percentage algorithm implementation

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, max

So I just stared programming in C a few days ago and I have this program which takes an unsorted file full of integers, sorts it using quicksort 
**1st algorithm**

Any suggestions on what I have done wrong in this?

Comment: If you are sorting the list, can you not just return the element at index `0.9*numberOfNumbers` ?

Comment: No, because I might have duplicates in the file, so I need to jump over them so to say. I do take them into account when calculating the % but when I find one I simply go to the next one to check if it's not the same as the previous one.

Comment: It should be at the index 0.9*numberOfNumbers - 1

Comment: @vidit 0.91*numberOfNumbers after sorting (Danielle, you can check if the previous item is a duplicate; and then count forward until it isn't - if necessary)

Comment: Which one do you mean? I do have to take the duplicates into account as well.

Comment: By definition the item at 0.91 * the length is greater than 90% of the items in the list.

Comment: why not delete the repeated numbers when you read the file and after delete use the formula?

Comment: This won't work for a huge list of numbers. In that case, even the number at 90.1% might be the output. Also I have to take the duplicates into account, when calculating the %. I will post an example in one minute.

Comment: I added an example for a file with duplicates in it.

Comment: What would you expect from a list like "1 1 1 1 1 ... 1"? Does 1 "exceed at least 90% of the numbers", even though it is both the largest and the smallest number in the list? I think that the question as stated leaves enough corner cases that a fully correct answer might be hard to produce... And in fact, depending on the exact specification, some of those corner cases may not even have solutions...

Comment: As you  can see, You have to calculate 90% of the numbers, with the duplicates in it. And then jump over the duplicates instead of deleting them.

Comment: If I am understanding your question right, you are attempting to create an algorithm to identify  the first element of a collection that would represent a value equaling the 90th percentile of that collection.  ***[would this work for you?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements)***

Comment: The break fixed my algorithm. That is what I was missing.

Comment: @Danielle - A late comment, regarding _The break fixed my algorithm. That is what I was missing._  I looked back through the edits on your original post, and now agree with your assesment.  (My comment was targeted toward a previous version (edit) that did not require the break. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue in your code is that you need a break case for your second algorithm, once you find the output. Also, you cannot declare variables in your for loop, except under certain conditions. I'm not sure how you got it to compile.

Comment: _Also, you can't declare variables in your for loop. I'm not sure how you got it to compile_  ***I disagree***.  You ***CAN*** declare variables in a for loop, or just about any other block.  Your statement is incorrect.  If you fix that, or provide some rational that is accurate, I will undo my downvote.  Also, your assertion that a `break case` is necessary is questionable.  The loop will exit when the condition `(array[x] == array[x + 1])` is not longer true.

Comment: @ryyker [Here you go.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287863/c-for-loop-int-initial-declaration) Also, my statement referred to an earlier version of the code above. If you scroll back through the edits, you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks.  will retract the down vote.  I also took a look at the OP code, break will work where you suggested.  I would suggest though being specific on C specification (eg. C99, C11, et al.) if you can ***when pointing out some feature that is provided (or is missing)*** such as not being able to create a variable within a loop. I do that all the time :) ***( Just discovered my vote is locked in (time limit)  If you can make a small edit to your post, then I will come back later and give you an up vote.  Thanks )***

Comment: Alright. This is my first semester doing C, and I wasn't aware there different conditions where a compiler would accept a declaration in a for loop. I'll have to look more into that option.

Comment: You can always declare variables in for loops, except if you are using an archaic compiler which doesn't support the 14 years old C99 standard. Even visual studio 2013 supports that.

Comment: @Jack Try this one ;-) http://ideone.com/DOyihV Codepad uses gcc to compile your code in background with the following options: "-O -fmessage-length=0 -fno-merge-constants -fstrict-aliasing -fstack-protector-all" If the flag "-std=c99" was added it would compile C99 code too.

Comment: Well, I didn't say without C99. Of course in pure C89 it is not allowed, but recent compilers which don't support C99 for loops initial declaration are extremely seldom. (codepad is not a compiler)

Comment: No problem at all ;-)

Answer (score 5):

***From what you have described***, it sounds like you are almost there.  You are attempting to get the first element of a collection that has a value equal to (or just greather than) 90% of all the other members of the collection.  You have already done the sort.  The rest should be simply following these steps (if I have understood your question):

***1)*** sort collection into an into array  (you've already done this I think)
***2)*** count numbers in collection, store in `float n;`  //number of elements in collection
***3)*** index through sorted array to the 0.9*n th element, (pick first one beyond that point not a duplicate of previous)
***4)*** display results

***Here is an implementation*** (sort of, I did not store `n`) of what I have described:  (ignore the random number generator, et al., it is just a fast way to get an array)

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
#include <windows.h>
int randomGenerator(int min, int max);
int NotUsedRecently (int number);
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b);

int main(void)
{
    int array[1000];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        array[i]=randomGenerator(1, 1000);
        Sleep(1);
    }

    //sort array
    qsort(array, 1000, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

    //pick the first non repeat 90th percent and print
    for(i=900;i<999;i++)
    {
        if(array[i+1] != array[i])
        {
            printf("this is the first number meeting criteria: %d", array[i+1]);
            break;
        }
    }
    getchar();  

    return 0;
}






int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}


int randomGenerator(int min, int max)
{
    int random=0, trying=0;

    trying = 1;         
    srand(clock());
    while(trying)
    {

        random = (rand()/32767.0)*(max+1);
        (random >= min) ? (trying = 0) : (trying = 1);
    }

    return random;
}
```

And here is the output for my first randomly generated array (centering around the 90th percentile), compared against what the algorithm selected:  Column on left is the element number, on the right is the sorted list of randomly generated integers.  (notice it skips the repeats to ensure smallest value *past* 90%)

[image]
[image]

***In summary***:  As I said, I think you are *already*, almost there.  Notice how similar this section of my code is to yours:

[image]

You have something already, very similar.  Just modify it to start looking at 90% index of the array (whatever that is), then just pick the first value that is not equal to the previous.

Answer (score 1):

According this part:

```
int output = array[(int)(floor(0.9*count)) + 1];
int x = (floor(0.9*count) + 1);

while (array[x] == array[x + 1])
{
    x = x + 1;
}
printf(" %d ", output);
```

In while you do not check if `x` has exceeded `count`... (What if all the top 10% numbers are equal?)
You set `output` in first line and print it in last, but do not do antything with it in meantime. (So all those lines in between do nothing).

You definitely are on the right track.