# string function that passes in a string and integer

Tags: c++, c

I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I'm trying to make a function that passes in an integer and string and returns a string.

```
string convertThousands(int val, string roman)
{
        piece = (val / THOUSANDS);
        for (int i = 0; i < piece; i++)
        {
            roman += 'M';
        }
        val %= THOUSANDS;
        return roman;
}
```

in my main function I would call it like below:

```
string roman;
roman = convertThousands;
```

Comment: there is no string type in the C standard. is it a type that you defined? share the string type definition if it's the case

Comment: aditionally: is lopp head declaration of a variable valid in pure C? My teacher told me it isn't, but he isn't that crack, and I'm not that sure.

Comment: Your call to `convertThousands()` does not match its prototype.

Comment: by not working do you mean it doesn't even compile? Because I will not.

Comment: @Zaibis It's allowed in C99. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287863/c-for-loop-int-initial-declaration

Comment: @user3229707 I dont want to sounds like "go read a book", but follow a tutorial on C to understands the synthax and the basic string mechanims

Comment: @Zaibis It's allowed, since C99.  (It wasn't allowed in K&R C nor in the original C standard, but it has been legal for well over 20 years now.)

Comment: @MOHAMED The OP tagged both C and C++. Chances are that this could be (legal) C++.

Comment: I'm pretty sure i'm doing C++, but the course i'm taking is an upgrade of C so I might still be using some c somewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char* string;

#define THOUSANDS 1000

string convertThousands(int *val, string roman){
    int piece = (*val / THOUSANDS);
    for (int i = 0; i < piece; i++){
        strcat(roman , "M");
    }
    *val %= THOUSANDS;
    return roman;
}

int main(){
    string roman = malloc(1024);
    strcpy(roman, "");
    int year = 2014;
    roman = convertThousands(&year, roman);
    printf("%d, %s\n", year, roman);
    free(roman);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int THOUSANDS = 1000;

string convertThousands(int &val, string roman){
    int piece = val / THOUSANDS;
    for (int i = 0; i < piece; i++){
        roman += 'M';
    }
    val %= THOUSANDS;
    return roman;
}

int main(){
    string roman("");
    int val = 2014;
    roman = convertThousands(val, roman);
    cout << val << ',' << roman << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should at least note, that this is plain C.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to call a function in a proper way:

```
string roman;
int val = 2014;
roman = convertThousands(val, roman);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main function should look like this:

```
string roman;
roman = convertThousands(100, roman);
```

*Note that 100 should be replaced by whatever value you want to pass to this function.*

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `convertThousands` method in a proper way. You should do it like this

```
int value = 2015;
std::string roman;
roman = convertThousands(value, roman);
```

Inside your method, I don't see anything wrong, so it should run properly.

Comment: it is supposed to be "C", not C++. And there are other things wrong inside that method

Comment: oops, looks like I haven't read it carefully.

Comment: well, no downvote. maybe the "C" tag is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the syntactical grammar is correct.

You are still not passing the arguements to the function. How will the function know what is the "val" and "string" that the function will operate on.

```
main()
{
//caller function
int val = 2000;
string resultstr;
resultstr = convertthousands(val, roman)
}

string convertthousands(int val, string roman)
{
/* called function performs operation on val and roman and can return string after required operation */
}
```