# Declaring a variable inside a for loop; getting error with c2000 compiler

Tags: c, variables, for-loop, compiler-errors, texas-instruments

I am working on a C project for a TI TMS320x DSP with the C2000 compiler. I tried to initialized a loop variable directly inside a for loop, but somehow I get a compiler error:

Code:

```
for (int TabCnt = 0; TabCnt < 10; TabCnt++)
{
    x++;
}
```

Error:

```
error #20: identifier "TabCnt" is undefined
```

I figure this might be a wrong compiler setting? If I declare the variable outside of the loop, it works perfectly.

Comment: You need to enforce `c99` mode in the compiler setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: for loop int initial declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287863/c-for-loop-int-initial-declaration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are using a compiler that supports only C89.

This syntax:

```
for (int TabCnt = 0; TabCnt < 10; TabCnt++)
```

is only valid since C99. The solution is either enable C99 if supported, or declare variables in the beginning of a block, e.g:

```
void foo()
{
    int x = 0;
    int TabCnt;
    for (TabCnt = 0; TabCnt < 10; TabCnt++)
    {
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I thought it might be something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
int TabCnt;

for(TabCnt = 0; TabCnt < 10; TabCnt++)
```

will solve your problem as it seems your compiler doesn't support C99.

Try compiling with `-std=c99` since the syntax you have is allowed only from C99

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking how to enable c99 in Code Composer Studio (*the editor used to develop embedded C for Texas Instruments microcontrollers*), go to Project -> Properties and then in the left hand side go to Build -> C2000 compiler -> Advanced Options -> Language options. You can select c99 in the drop-down menu of the "C Dialect" parameter.
[image]

Note: I am using CCS v11.2.0.00007