# What is the fastest way to increment a string in perl?

Tags: string, perl

I would like to append a string in perl within a loop in a fast way, without having to copy the string for each iteration. I'm looking for something like StringBuilder from Java or C#.

I currently know the following alternatives in mind, in order to do 'a += b'.

1. a .= b # concat
2. a = join('', a, b); # join
3. push @a, b # array push

I am not interested in copying all string to the other. I need to copy one character per time, or append small strings foreach iteration. I am trying to solve the following problem: compress the input string 'aaabbccc' to '3a2b3c'. So the idea is to iterate over the input string, check how many repeated characters we have, and then append to the output in the compressed way. What is the most efficient to perform this in perl ?

[Here is a link](https://github.com/andrepontesmelo/CtCI-6th-Edition-Perl/tree/master/Chapter1/6_String_Compression) to the problem I was trying to solve. I's slightly different though.

Comment: Have you considered `s/([a-z])\1+/($+[0] - $-[0]) . $1/eg`?

Comment: If you have `aabbaa` would you compress it to `2a2b2a` or to `4a2b`?

Comment: If I have aabbaa, then it should be compressed to 2a2b2a.

Comment: Ok :) and if you have single char `abb` would you use a 1 or nothing, i.e. `1a2b` or `a2b`?

Comment: If you have single char, would use nothing. So compress('aaabcddd') = '3abc3d'.  ;)

Comment: Yes that make sense, else it would not be a compression. Also for two chars there will be no compression since the length of `aa` and `2a` is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For comparsion, I tried to test different versions for solving your **actual** problem of compressing the string. Here is my test script `test.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);
use Inline C => './compress_c.c';

my $str_len = 10000;
my @chars = qw(a b c d);
my $str;
$str .= [@chars]->[rand 4] for 1 .. $str_len;

cmpthese(
    -1,
    {
        compress_array => sub { compress_array( $str ) },
        compress_regex => sub { compress_regex( $str ) },
        compress_str   => sub { compress_str( $str ) },
        compress_c     => sub { compress_c( $str ) },
    }
);

# Suggested by @melpomene in the comments   
sub compress_regex {
    return $_[0] =~ s/([a-z])\1+/($+[0] - $-[0]) . $1/egr;
}

sub compress_array {
    my $result = '';

    my @chrs = split //, $_[0];

    my $prev = $chrs[0];
    my $count = 1;
    my @result;
    for my $i ( 1..$#chrs ) {
        my $char = $chrs[$i];
        if ( $prev eq $char ) {
            $count++;
            next if $i < $#chrs;
        }
        if ( $count > 1) {
            push @result, $count, $prev;
        }
        else {
            push @result, $prev;
        }
        if ( ( $i == $#chrs ) and ( $prev ne $char ) ) {
            push @result, $char;
            last;
        }
        $count = 1;
        $prev = $char;
    }

    return join '', @result;
}

sub compress_str {
    my $result = '';
    my $prev = substr $_[0], 0, 1;
    my $count = 1;
    my $lastind = (length $_[0]) - 1;
    for my $i (1 .. $lastind) {
        my $char = substr $_[0], $i, 1;
        if ( $prev eq $char ) {
            $count++;
            next if $i < $lastind;
        }

        if ( $count > 1) {
            $result .= $count;
        }
        $result .= $prev;
        if ( ( $i == $lastind ) and ( $prev ne $char ) ) {
            $result .= $char;
            last;
        }
        $count = 1;
        $prev = $char;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

where `compress_c.c` is:

```
SV *compress_c(SV* str_sv) {
    STRLEN len;
    char* str = SvPVbyte(str_sv, len);

    SV* result = newSV(len);
    char *buf = SvPVX(result);

    char prev = str[0];
    int count = 1;
    int j = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < len; i++ )
    {
    char cur = str[i];
        if ( prev == cur ) {
            count++;
            if ( i < (len - 1) )
                continue;
        }

        if ( count > 1) {
            buf[j++] = count + '0';  // assume count is less than 10
        }

        buf[j++] = prev;
        if ( (i == (len - 1)) && (prev != cur) ) buf[j++] = cur;
        count = 1;
        prev = cur;
    }

    buf[j] = '\0';
    SvPOK_on(result);
    SvCUR_set(result, j);
    return result;
}
```

The result of running `perl test.pl`:

```
                  Rate compress_array  compress_str compress_regex    compress_c
compress_array   311/s             --          -42%           -45%          -99%
compress_str     533/s            71%            --            -6%          -98%
compress_regex   570/s            83%            7%             --          -98%
compress_c     30632/s          9746%         5644%          5273%            --
```

Which shows that regex version is slightly faster than the string version. However, the C version is the fastest, and it is about 50 times as fast as the regex version.

Note: I tested this on my Ubuntu 16.10 laptop (Intel Core i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the edits and the comments! I was wondering how to get rid of the
`malloc` call so I did not have to allocate the buffer twice. I have
some questions: 1. Is `SvGETMAGIC(str_sv)` necessary when we are using
`SvPVbyte(str_sv, len)`? According to
[`perlapi`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html) `SvPV()` handles get
magic. 2. Why the braced block after `SvGETMAGIC()`? I cannot see any
reason to add a local scope here. 3. What do you mean by *"Removed
Unicode bug"* (comment in the answer revision history)?

Comment: ... 4. Also the comment *"Fixed a compile error (`int` inside of `for`)"*. It should be valid to declare variables in the `for` loop specification in C99, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1287867/2173773).

Comment: I've [commited here](https://github.com/andrepontesmelo/CtCI-6th-Edition-Perl/tree/master/Chapter1/6_String_Compression) the benchmarks for the original problem that I was trying to solve.  It's a slightly different problem. I've got same results though.

Comment: 1. Oops, you're right about `SvPVbyte` already doing `SvGETMAGIC`. 2. Depending on the version of C, you can't mix declarations and code. Var declarations can only be found at the start of a block or after another var declaration. 3. I (effectively) replaced SvPV with SvPVbytes. You can't use SvPV without separately checking the `UTF8` flag. 4. Switching `gcc` to C99 mode requires a switch that wasn't used when my `perl` was built.

Answer (score 2):

I've performed the following benchmark in several ways to perform that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $dna;
$dna .= [qw(G A T C)]->[rand 4] for 1 .. 10000;

sub frequency_concat {
    my $result = '';

    for my $idx (0 .. length($dna) - 1) {
            $result .= substr($dna, $idx, 1);
    }

    return $result;
 }

 sub frequency_join {
    my $result = '';

    for my $idx (0 .. length($dna) - 1) {
            $result = join '', $result, substr($dna,$idx,1);
    }

    return $result;
}

sub frequency_list_push {
       my @result = ();

       for my $idx (0 .. length($dna) - 1) {
               push @result, substr($dna,$idx,1);
       }

       return join '', @result;
 }

 sub frequency_list_prealloc {
            my @result = (' ' x length($dna));

            for my $idx (0 .. length($dna) - 1) {
                    $result[$idx] = substr($dna,$idx,1);
            }

            return join '', @result;
 }


cmpthese(-1, # Run each for at least 1 second(s)   {
               concat => \&frequency_concat,
               join => \&frequency_join,
               list_push => \&frequency_list_push,
               list_list_prealloc => \&frequency_list_prealloc
       }
   );
```

The results below have shown that the concat (a . b) is the fastest operation. I don't understand why, since this will need to make several copies of the string.

```
                    Rate         join   list_push list_list_prealloc          concat
join               213/s           --        -38%               -41%        -74%
list_push          342/s          60%          --                -5%        -58%
list_list_prealloc 359/s          68%          5%                 --        -56%
concat             822/s         285%        140%               129%          --
```

Comment: Your "list prealloc" case doesn't preallocate an array. It allocates a single element, which is a long string.

Comment: IMHO, would be better benchmark the **whole** problem - e.g, counting the number of occurences of a character in a string.

Comment: I tested this on my Ubuntu 16.10 laptop (Intel Core i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz), and got similar results. I removed the call to `substr` and replaced it with a constant 1 char string instead. Now, `concat` was the fastest with 3229/s. I also implemented a C version with preallocation (using [`Inline::C`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Inline-C/lib/Inline/C.pod)) that was aproximately 90 times faster than the `concat` version (284350/s). The reason I removed the `substr` call was to be able to more easily compare the C version with the Perl versions.

Comment: melpomene: Now I see. ' ' x length($dna) is one string. I've fixed it with (' ') x length($dna), which would prealloc the array. Same order of benchmark results.