# Variable declaration in for loop - Intellisense stuck with C89 standard?

Tags: c, loops, variables, intellisense, declaration

I have a C project which i open in VisualStudio 2019 with the "Open folder" option. I added a CppProperties.json to get Intellisense running, but now it throws errors if i try to declare a variable in a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
}

error: E0029 expected an expression
error: E0020 identifier "i" is undefined
```

I searched StackOverflow already and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287863/c-for-loop-int-initial-declaration) where someone mentions that the declaration of variables in for loops was added in the C99 standard.

In the VisualStudio documentation it says you should add "-std=C99" to your project settings, but i have no project file (because I opened it with the "Open Folder" option) and therefore no project settings.

Is there a way to tell Intellisense what C standard to use anyways ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visual Studio and the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler is, first and foremost, a C++ compiler and environment. C has been a third-class citizen in the Visual Studio system for a long time, and not until very recently the compiler itself started to support C99.

Comment: Using MSVC as a C compiler is a bit like using your washing machine to wash your dishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it: Just add

```
"compilerSwitches": "-std=c99",
```

to your CppProperties.json.