# How to count occurrences of specific char in 2D array in C language?

Tags: arrays, c, 2d

I have an array [8][8]

```
char d[ROWS][COLS] = {
        {0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2},
        {2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0},
        {0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2},
        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0},
        {0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3},
        {3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0}};


int countOccurrences(char d[ROWS][COLS], int i, int j, int res)
{
    res = 0;
    for (i=0; i<=ROWS; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=COLS; j++){
            if ('2' == d[ROWS][COLS])
            res++;
            
        }
    }      
    return res;
    printf("score%d", res);

}
```

my code doesn't work and I need to find and count the occurrences in 2D array and print it out

Comment: Arrays start at index 0 and end at index "size-1". Therefore `i=0; i<=ROWS;` doesn't make any sense, you access the array out of bounds.

Comment: https://shrib.com/#Mara4rMnyRK

here 's my code, i made changes you suggested me but somehow it return crazy numbers, i would appreciate your help) anyways its not for school or anything just trying to learn, could you please check my code briefly and tell me why it doesnt work as it should?

Comment: If you still have problems after implementing the suggestions in the posted answers, then you could ask a new question and post the code there.

Answer (score 2):

I made a comment, but I will also go ahead and respond with the fixed function. There were three main issues in the code that I'll point out:

1. In your code, you have numbers within the array, but then you try comparing a char to a number (`'2' == 2` is false), so that means your result will be 0 over all
2. The print statement was *after* the `return`, which means it won't actually run.
3. the if statement `if (2 == d[ROWS][COLS])` is *always* going to check the number at position `ROWS` and `COLS`. The first issue there is that `ROWS` and `COLS` aren't changing positions, that's a constant; you want to check at the position `i` and `j`. Second, since array's in C are zero-based, accessing `d` at position `[ROWS][COLS]` will actually point to some unknown memory space since that's beyond the scope of the array, but that's just an interesting fact.

The following code should fix the problems I pointed out above:

```
char d[ROWS][COLS] = {
    {0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2},
    {2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0},
    {0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2},
    {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
    {3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0},
    {0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3},
    {3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0}};

int countOccurrences(char d[ROWS][COLS], int i, int j, int res) {
    res = 0;

    // NOTICE that it is now i < ROWS and j < COLS instead of
    // i <= ROWS and j <= COLS to deal with what I mentioned
    // before about the zero-based indexing in C, which means
    // we need to stop BEFORE ROWS and COLS
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            if (2 == d[i][j])
                res++;
        }
    }      

    printf("score%d", res);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: There's still an issue with `i<=ROWS` and `j<=COLS` (from the original code) - this is going to cause `d[i][j]` to exceed the array bounds.

Comment: correct @sj95126 -- I fixed the code to correctly correspond with that.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code:

- You have a char `'2'`, which will transform to whatever character encoding that your system use, in my case, ASCII, which will be saved by the value `50`, and you are comparing it with the value `2`, which will return `false`.
- You're comparing `d[ROWS][COLS]` every time, that's probably not what you want.
- In your loop, there will be times that it will try to access `d[ROW][...]`, `d[...][COL]`, which will create an out of bounds error.
- You make too many unnecessary arguments for your function.
- You `return` before `printf()`, so `printf()` never get executed.

Suggested code:

```c
char d[ROWS][COLS] = {
        {'0', '2', '0', '2', '0', '2', '0', '2'},
        {'2', '0', '2', '0', '2', '0', '2', '0'},
        {'0', '2', '0', '2', '0', '2', '0', '2'},
        {'1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0'},
        {'0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1'},
        {'3', '0', '3', '0', '3', '0', '3', '0'},
        {'0', '3', '0', '3', '0', '3', '0', '3'},
        {'3', '0', '3', '0', '3', '0', '3', '0'}};


int countOccurrences(char anotherName[], int ROWS, int COLS)
{
    int res = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<COLS; j++){
            if ('2' == anotherName[i][j])
            ++res;
            
        }
    }      
    printf("score%d", res);
    return res;
} 
// You should call it like this: int something = countOccurrences(d, ROWS, COLS);
```

Comment: I would be careful making the assumption that [C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287863/c-for-loop-int-initial-declaration) is being used specifically about declaring the variables `i` and `j` in the for loops

Comment: @charlie-map I've edited my code, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @charlie-map On SO we have the policy that unless a specific older standard is explicitly mentioned in the question, we can assume the current standard. Which is C17. Therefore your advise is harmful and the edit made the code much worse.

Comment: shrib.com/#Mara4rMnyRK here 's my code, i made changes you suggested me but somehow it return crazy numbers, i would appreciate your help) anyways its not for school or anything just trying to learn, could you please check my code briefly and tell me why it doesnt work as it should?

Comment: @HazelHochmann Have my code fixed your error?

Comment: @justANewbie not really, probably i have messed something else, how should i call that function properly?

Comment: @HazelHochmann I've edited my answer again.