# I got this error when make the c file. How can I solve it?

Tags: c

How can I solve this problem?

error: expected an expression

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
     ^
```

Function that I try to implement:

```
void initRacks(struct rack_t *racks, int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    racks[i].widthA = i + 2.5;
    racks[i].widthB = i + 1.5;
  }
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've shared (assuming modern C). There may be a syntax error somewhere _before_ that code.

Comment: @Brian61354270 The code won't work if compiled under C standard below C99

Comment: If it is the problem, the easiest would be to move the definition of `i` before the for loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. moving i out of loop worked. But why can't I use it in the loop construct?

Comment: Read the previous comments. This construct was introduced in C99. Your compiler might be implementing an older standard, or configured to comply with older standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which version your compiler is.
Declaring the `int i;`  above the for loop will solve the error.

More detailed answer: [C for loop int initial declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287863/c-for-loop-int-initial-declaration)