# Compilation Error: Fprintf throws parse error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, compilation

I am trying to detect an error so I included in my program some traces.
The problem is that after that, it doesn't compile, giving me next error:

```
../src/DR700_API.c:46: parse error before `*'
```

I just added an fprintf at the beginning of each function:

```
fprintf(stdout,"_name_of_function_");
```

Commenting all fprintf it compiles right, so there's the error. I can't dispense with them as i want to track other error in execution time.

Here's a little example:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                          
#include <stdlib.h>

ImprFunc *DR700_new()                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                           
    fprintf(stdout,"DR700_new");                                                                                                           
    ImprFunc *impr = (ImprFunc *)malloc(sizeof(DR700_ImprFunc));                                                                            
    if (impr == NULL)                                                                                                                       
        return NULL;  
...


../src/DR700_API.c:46: parse error before `*'
../src/DR700_API.c:47: `impr' undeclared (first use in this function)
../src/DR700_API.c:47: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../src/DR700_API.c:47: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [../obj/DR700_API.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your setup doesn't allow mixed code and declarations (as per C89). If you wish to not affect project setup - try to keep declarations before any code. In your example it means

```
ImprFunc *impr = (ImprFunc *)malloc(sizeof(DR700_ImprFunc));
fprintf(stdout,"DR700_new");
```

instead of

```
fprintf(stdout,"DR700_new");
ImprFunc *impr = (ImprFunc *)malloc(sizeof(DR700_ImprFunc));
```

Or alternatively - add `-std=c99` (as was mentioned in comments).

Comment: or add -std=c99 into the build flags. But for new gcc it is not actual as it uses -std=c11 by default

Comment: I did it the first way and it worked fine.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In early versions of C, variables had to be declared at the beginning of a block.

[C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) allows to mix declarations and statements arbitrarily (e.g. see [Variable declaration placement in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/288441/3235496) and [Where can I legally declare a variable in C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321564/3235496)).

You could try compiling with `--std=c99` / `--std=c11` which will allow you to declare variables anywhere (if supported in your version of gcc. See [Status of C99 features in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html) and [C11Status](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status)).

C99 is, for the most part, backward compatible with C89.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.