# How do I know whether c89 or c99 is applied by cl.exe?

Tags: c, c99, c89

I just came across this term in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288441/variable-declaration-placement-in-c),

how do I check which rule is actually used by my compiler?

Or is it possible to specify a rule for `cl.exe`?

Comment: In fact almost every question can be answered by "Read the manual", why are we still sticking to SO instead of "Read the manual" ?

Comment: Microsoft *still* doesn't support C99, even in Visual Studio 2010, so you can safely assume C89.

Comment: @user198729: because the question is "How do I know ...?", not "Is ...?"

Answer (score 5):

C99 compilers must define a preprcessor symbol `__STDC_VERSION__` with value 199901L which C90 one shouldn't do this (nothing prevent them to do so and still be compliant with C90, but I doubt they do). Obviously nothing is sure for non compliant compilers or compilers in non compliant mode.  And there are still the question of bugs and transition (last time I checked for instance, g++ didn't still define the equivalent macro at the value mandated for C++98 while most people I know think it would be more usefull for them to do so instead of waiting for the implementation of `export`).

Comment: `__STDC_VERSION__` (two underscores)

Answer (score 2):

cl.exe, the Microsoft compiler? It doesn't support C99, mostly.