# Does C require that variables are declared at start of scope?

Tags: c

The C language requires that all variables used in the program should be declared before any other statements.

Why was this of significance? Was it for readability? If it was for readability, then why don't other languages follow the same rule?

I personally prefer declaring all my variables at the very start.

Moderators: Please delete if this is off-topic or already been asked. I was just keen to know improve my knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: Not the current C Standard. In C99 variable declarations and code can be intermixed at will.

Comment: that's not mandated anymore in the `C99` standard.

Comment: C99 do not have this limitation. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288441/variable-declaration-placement-in-c

Comment: now it's not mandatory anymore. Anyway it wasn't for readability. C is a very old language and one of its peculiar features is that a C file can be compiled with just one parsing. I think that the earliest version of the language made the choice to declare variable at the beginning for simplify the parsing

Comment: ahha! good to know...if one of you can answer back, I can then accept it :) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like other people said in comments now it's not mandatory anymore. Anyway it wasn't for readability. C is a very old language and one of its peculiar features is that a C file can be compiled with just one parsing. I think that the earliest version of the language made the choice to declare variable at the beginning for simplify the parsing