# Have compiler declare and locate debug pointer variable

Tags: c, unit-testing, pointers, initialization

Say I have a two functions like the ones below:

```
unsigned char PlusTwo(unsigned char value)
{
    return (value + 2);
}
unsigned char PlusTwoUsingPtr(unsigned char *value)
{
    return (*value + 2);
}
```

If I want to test the first function while I'm developing, no problem, all I have to do is this:

```
PlusTwo(8);
```

The compiler will automatically place a constant somewhere in memory for me.  However, to test the second function, it gets more complicated.  First I have to declare a variable, then pass the function the address of the variable:

```
unsigned char eight = 8;
PlusTwoUsingPtr(&eight);
```

This isn't horribly time consuming, but it is annoying (particularly in C89/ANSI where [variables have to be declared at the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/288441/316857) of a function block).  Is there some trick that will allow me to just test this function in one line of code, having the compiler declare & place a constant somewhere for me to point to?

Comment: A pointer to an implicitly-created wouldn't cut it. According to its signature, it's entirely reasonable (even without casts and UB and the like) that `PlusTwoUsingPtr` writes to `*value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a compound literal with a scalar type:

```
 PlusTwoUsingPtr(&((unsigned char){8}));
```

Compound literal is a feature introduced in C99.
For information the object is mutable (with static storage duration) and you can also modify it in your function.

Comment: Interesting... that seems to work. Is 8 stored like a literal string?

Comment: @Robert no, it also has static storage duration but it is modifiable.

Comment: And it seems GCC supports it even without explicitly using the C99 standard, as it's part of GCC's default extensions to C89.

Comment: @JAB - Nice! That was my next question.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around the compound literal, `&(unsigned char){8}` is fine.