# C variable declaration place

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable declaration placement in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288441/variable-declaration-placement-in-c)

I really dont understand why when I declare variable 'm' like in snipped code below why it doesn't work???I declare m before I use it so what's the point?? thanks

```
    int main(){

    int a[] = {2,-4,6,47,59,-6,0};
    sort(a, 7);

    int m;
    for(m = 0; m < 7; m++){
        printf("%d ",a[m]);
    }
}
```

But if I put declaration at beggining, above the array, it works.

Comment: What options did you compile with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are compiling in ANSI C mode. In C89, variable declaration is allowed only at the beginning of a block.

Since C99, this restriction has been removed. Compile with `-std=c99` which will allow you to declare variables anywhere.

Comment: I use compiler within Visual Studio 2010, I begin C++ project and in properties change to Compile as C code (/TC) What does it mean??

Comment: Visual Studio supports only few C99 features. So you may have to declare variables at the beginning of a block. Simply move `int m;` to the top of main().For more information: [Visual Studio support for new C / C++ standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards).

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know in C, all declarations must be above the code

Comment: That used to be the case in C89, it is not so since C99.

Comment: I studied C as an introductory Course back in 2001, I blame my instructor for not telling me this info lol

Comment: Probably he didn't know that then, it was only two years.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a compiler that supports C99 partially(or doesn't support it at all), in which,  in-place variable declaration is forbidden.

Using such a compiler would need you to declare your variables before an "executable" code.

This was a restriction in C89 and previous.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually an answer but I can't comment on questions yet.
I agree with people's answer above regarding the C implementation you;re using is causing the error. What I suggest you try is for (int m = 0, ...) for two reasons: to see if it compiles, and scope (from the looks of it you don't need m outside the for loop)
Hope this helps