# Declaration is not allowed here in C

Tags: c

```
//assumed mean method
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
/*  mvx--Middle value of observation(x)
    xup--Upper point of observation
    xlow--Lower point of observation
    f--frequency of observation
    Tf--Total of frequency
    n--number of observation
    a--Assumed mean
    c--class length
    d--difference of observation and assumed mean
    fd--multiplication of frequency and difference
    Tfd--total of fd
    mean--finally mean  */

    int mvx[100],xup[100],xlow[100],f[100],Tf=0,n,i,a,c,d[100],fd[100];
    float mean,Tfd=0;

    printf("\t\tProgram to find mean with assumed mean method:\n\n");
    printf("Enter the number of observation:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the data:\n");
    printf("X-->");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("\t");
        //taking data from user:
        scanf("%d",&xlow[i]);
        scanf("%d",&xup[i]);
    }
    printf("Printing the observation:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        //just printing data
        printf("%d-%d\t",xlow[i],xup[i]);
    }
    printf("\nMV(x)-->");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        //finding middle value of x amd prntfing it
        mvx[i]=xup[i]+xlow[i]/2;
        printf("\t%d",mvx[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter the frequency:\n");
    printf("F-->");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        //taking frequency from user and making total of it
        printf("\t");
        scanf("%d",&f[i]);
        Tf=Tf+f[i];
    }
    //finding class length
    c=xup[1]-xlow[1];
    //assuming mean from the user
    printf("Assume any observation from data:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("D-->");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        //calculating d and printing
        printf("\t");
        d[i]=(mvx[i]-a)/c;
        printf("%d",d[i]);
    }
    printf("\nFD-->");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        //calculating fd and printing
        fd[i]=f[i]*d[i];
        printf("\t%d",fd[i]);
        Tfd=Tfd+fd[i];
    }
    //calculating mean
    mean=a+(Tfd/Tf)*c;
    printf("\nMean of the data is:%f",mean);
    getch();
}
```

These is a program to find the mean of continuous data with class length by assumed mean method.
All the other information of variables I have added in the comment part in the program.
There are 2 same errors of "declaration is not allowed here" where I have declared all variables.
I have tried a lot to get rid of it but I can't so please help me to get out from that..

Comment: Unrelated: stop fighting zero-based indexing. You gotta hug it sometime; may as well be now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an older compiler, I think all pre-C99 compilers, all the declarations in a function must come before any function calls. Move the line

```
clrscr();
```

after you have declared all the variables, i.e. move it after the line

```
float mean,Tfd=0;
```

You can use your existing code if your compiler supports C99 (through the use of a compiler flag, perhaps). Then you need to find how to enable it.

Comment: Some more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288441/variable-declaration-placement-in-c