# build error in code block for function gets

Tags: c, codeblocks

I want to make a simple variable for number of the round for a loop, so I tried my code

```
int size,counter,marks[size];
scanf("enter %d/n",&size);
for(counter=0;counter<size;counter++)
{
    scanf("%d",&marks[counter]);
}
```

and compiled with no error but in run, it just shows `"process returned -1073741571 <0*c00000FD>`.

so I tried `gets` function and it shows `"too many arguments to function 'gets' "`.

```
int size;
int counter;
int marks[size];
scanf("enter %d/n",&size);
for(counter=0;counter<size;counter++)
{
    gets("%d",&marks[counter]);
}
```

I'm using code::blocks 17.12 and the gnu compiler.

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please don't use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: i tried scanf and just  -1073741571 <0*c00000FD>  show up

Answer (score 1):

`size` must have a defined value, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int size;
    size = 5; // size must be constant
    int counter, marks[size];
    for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &marks[counter]);
    }
    //Printing it returns correct values:
    for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", marks[counter]);
    }
}
```

You can instead input it's value from the user if you want.

However, if for some reason, `size` is to be defined after the array is declared, use pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
int main()
{
    int size;
    int counter, *marks;
    size = 5; //declared after the array
    marks = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &marks[counter]);
    }
    //Printing it returns correct values:
    for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", marks[counter]);
    }
    //Don't forget to free the array in the end
    free(marks);
}
```

Comment: so if i put a const value and then put an scanf for it the problem will be solved?

Comment: This doesn't solve either problem in OP's code, unfortunately. The `scanf` format is wrong, and even if it was correct, the user's `size` input would crash if it was anything greater than 5. No need to [cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @ggorlen Why would it crash? And why is the format wrong? I would be happy to learn if there's something wrong with the code :)

Comment: Sure. This is for the top example. You allocate `5 * sizeof(int)` bytes for the `marks` array. Then you presumably ask the user to specify `size`. if the user enters anything larger than 5, the `for` loop will allow the user to write past the size of the array. This is fixed in the below example with `malloc`, but there's no good reason to `malloc` here, and the size is no longer specifiable for the user--you're stuck with 5.

Comment: @ggorlen You can substitute ```scanf``` for the numeral declarations here and that won't really break anything, I just meant to show they need to be declared a value first( 5 being a value). But I do agree it was confusing. Thanks for pointing that out :D

Comment: @ggorlen but that's exactly what you've done in your answer :P

Comment: `"enter %d/n"`? This doesn't work--you'll get a garbage `size` value back.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use `gets`. [It's dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

As for your error in the `scanf` example, the first problem is the line

```
int size,counter,marks[size];
```

which declares `marks` with the uninitialized `size` value. Try initializing `size` first, then declaring the `marks` array.

Your second problem is `scanf` formatting string. Use `scanf` to read formatted input, not output a prompt. Use `puts` or `printf` for that.

Here's a full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {  
    int size;
    printf("Enter a size value: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int marks[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &marks[i]);
    }

    printf("You entered: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", marks[i]);
    }

    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a sample run:

```
Enter a size value: 4
Enter element 0: 88
Enter element 1: 77
Enter element 2: 66
Enter element 3: 55
You entered: 88 77 66 55
```

If you're writing [ANSI C-compatible code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288441/variable-declaration-placement-in-c) you can use dynamic memory with `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {  
    int i, size, *marks;
    printf("Enter a size value: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    if (size < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid size specified\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    marks = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    if (!marks) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &marks[i]);
    }

    printf("You entered: ");

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", marks[i]);
    }

    free(marks);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`size` can have any value when the array `marks` is allocated because it is not initialized. The array might be smaller than the entered size and so marks are stored in non-allocated memory, giving you the error.

This is a possible solution, but it doesn't compile with strict ISO C90. Presumably your CodeBlocks uses GCC that accepts variable length arrays and mixed declarations and code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int size;
    printf("enter size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    int marks[size];
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++) {
        scanf("%d", &marks[counter]);
    }
    for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", counter, marks[counter]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, please don't say "build error" if you have a runtime error. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the new comments when writing the answer. Hope it helps, anyway.