# What is the principle of calculating the height of binary tree by recursive method?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, struct, binary-search-tree

This is the code that can find the height of the binary tree.

```
int PostOrderGetHeight(BinTree BT) { 
   int HL,HR,MaxH; 
   if(BT){ 
   HL = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Left); 
   HR = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Right); 
   MaxH = (HL>HR)?HL:HR;
   return (MaxH+1); 
   }
   else return 0;
}
```

My confusion is why HL, HR, MaxH don't need initialization and how does this recursive algorithm work to calculate the HL and HR.

Comment: None are used before they are set, so initialization is not needed.

Comment: @stark I see. But how can HL and HR be calculated? I can't understand this recursive algorithm...

Comment: @齐子佳 do you understand induction and recursive calculations in general? E.g. that there is a base case and a recursive case, and that it is the base case that sets `HL` + `HR` here. If not, try reading up on wikipedia, maybe here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: `HL`, `HR` and `MaxH` do not need initialization because they are assigned values before there values are used in later expressions. You know that each recursion has its own `HL`, `HR` and `MaxH` variables, right?

Comment: It finds the height by determining the height of the left and right sub-trees, determining which one of those is the largest, and adding 1 for its own node. An empty (sub-)tree has height 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing here is calculating the height of both sides of each tree. Every binary tree will have a right and left tree, which will have it's own height, until it reaches a terminal node with no height on either side.

[image]

Lets go through this example.

- We pass in A.
- It tries to calculate the height of B (a's left tree).

  - B tries to calculate the height of D (it's left tree).

    - D tries to calculate the height of it's left tree, and it returns zero.
    - D tries to calculate the height of its right tree (e)
    - e has no right or left trees (both return zero), so it return the max of (0) + 1
      as it's height
  - The max of D's right and left trees is 1, so the height of D is 1+1 = 2.
  - B has no right node so that returns zero.
  - The max of B's right and left nodes is 2, so B returns 2 +1 =3.
  - A calculates the height of C (it's right node, which will return 1)
  - Max of a's right and left is 3+1 =4.

Answer (score 2):

If BinTree BT is not equal to `NULL` then `HL` and `HR` get their values due to these statements

```
   HL = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Left); 
   HR = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Right);
```

Otherwise if for example `BT`, or `BT->Left`, or `BT->Right` are equal to `NULL` then a function call as for example

```
PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Left);
```

returns 0 because the function is defined like

```
int PostOrderGetHeight(BinTree BT) { 
   int HL,HR,MaxH; 
   if(BT){ 
      //...
   }
   else return 0;
        ^^^^^^^^ 
}
```

In each iteration of recursive calls of the function there is selected the maximum length between the left sub-tree and the right sub-tree.

Answer (score 1):

We can provide `PostOrderGetHeight` works for any tree by:

- proving it works for a tree of height 0, and
- proving that if it works for a tree of height *h*−1 or less, with *h* > 0, then it works for a tree of height *h*.

Thus, we will have proven it works for a tree of height 0, and therefore it works for a tree of height 1, and therefore for a tree of height 2, and 3, and so on.

To prove the first part, suppose `PostOrderGetHeight` is called with a tree of height 0. This means its root node, `BT` is null. In this case, when the routine is called the `else return 0;` statement executes, and the routine returns zero, which is correct.

To prove the second part, suppose `PostOrderGetHeight` is called with a tree of height *h*, with *h* > 0.

Then these two statements are executed:

```
HL = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Left); 
HR = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Right);
```

Observe that each of these calls `PostOrderGetHeight` with subtree of `BT`. Each subtree, `BT->Left` and `BT->Right`, must be a tree of height less than *h*. Since we have assumed `PostOrderGetHeight` works for trees of height up to *h*@-1, it returns the correct heights for these trees.

Then `MaxH = (HL>HR)?HL:HR;` sets `MaxH` to whichever is greater, the height of the left subtree or the height of the right subtree. At this point, we know that `BT` has height one greater than that maximum, because it includes that larger subtree plus one more node (the root node `BT`).

Then the statement `return (MAXH+1);` returns that height.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 


struct node  
{ 
    int data; 
    struct node* left; 
    struct node* right; 
}; 

int maxDepth(struct node* node)  
{ 
   if (node==NULL)  
       return 0; 
   else 
   { 

       int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left); 
       int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right); 


       if (lDepth > rDepth)  
           return(lDepth+1); 
       else return(rDepth+1); 
   } 
}  


struct node* newNode(int data)  
{ 
    struct node* node = (struct node*) 
                                malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    node->data = data; 
    node->left = NULL; 
    node->right = NULL; 

    return(node); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    struct node *root = newNode(1); 

    root->left = newNode(2); 
    root->right = newNode(3); 
    root->left->left = newNode(4); 
    root->left->right = newNode(5);  

    printf("Height of tree is %d", maxDepth(root)); 

    getchar(); 

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is clearer to declare and initialise the variables in one step. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288441/variable-declaration-placement-in-c) for more information.

```
int PostOrderGetHeight(BinTree BT) { 
   if(BT){ 
       const int HL = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Left); 
       const int HR = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Right); 
       const int MaxH = (HL>HR)?HL:HR;
       return (MaxH+1); 
   } else {
       return 0;
   }
}
```

If one node has no further `left` or `right` nodes, this is the end of this branch and `0` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Let's step through a tree (A) where the root has a left (B) and right (C) node, and its left node has a left node (D).  All other branches are NULL.

We pass A to `PostOrderGetHeight`, which calls `PostOrderGetHeight` on its two nodes (B) and (C).

When `PostOrderGetHeight` is called on B, it calls `PostOrderGetHeight` on its left node D, and on NULL (which is its right node).

That calls `PostOrderGetHeight` on D, which calls `PostOrderGetHeight` on its two NULL nodes.  Notice that calling `PostOrderGetHeight` on NULL return 0.

In this call `PostOrderGetHeight(D)`, HL and HR are set to zero.  So this effectively initializes them.  Then `MaxH` is set to zero, effectively initializing it.  Then the call to `PostOrderGetHeight(D)` returns `MaxH+1` which is 1.

Remember that `PostOrderGetHeight(D)` was called from `PostOrderGetHeight(B)` so it gets this answer 1 to set `HL` to 1.  The right branch of B is NULL, so `HR` gets set to 0, and `MaxH` gets set to 1, so `PostOrderGetHeight(B)` returns 2.

`PostOrderGetHeight(A)` called `PostOrderGetHeight(B)` and `PostOrderGetHeight(C)`.  Since C has two NULL branches, the call to `PostOrderGetHeight(C)` returns 1.  This sets `HL` to 2 returned from `PostOrderGetHeight(B)` and `HR` to 1 returned from `PostOrderGetHeight(C)`, making `MaxH` set to 2.  Thus `PostOrderGetHeight(A)` will return 3, which is the height of tree A.

Answer (score 0):

The general recursive algorithm relies on the fact that the height of a binary tree is the greater of height of its left and right sub-trees plus 1. 
The height of the empty tree is 0.

That's a very basic kind of recursion. The trivial case is 0 and more complex cases rely on working out the same thing for sub-parts of the problem and combining them except in the trivial case!

It's a bit like saying the height of a brick wall is the height of the wall with one brick taken off plus one, with the height of no wall being 0.
OK, that's a mad way to measure walls but it's not uncommon in computing!

`BinTree` will be a pointer. So the line `if(BT)` will be false if `BT` is `NULL` (the empty tree) and the function returns a height of zero (jumping straight to `else return 0`).

NB: `return 0;` would do here. There's no need for an `else` because both sides of the if-statement return.

So now you look at the detail of the if-true branch.

```
HL = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Left); 
HR = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Right); 
MaxH = (HL>HR)?HL:HR;
return (MaxH+1);
```

`HL` (meaning height left) is the height of the left side of the tree from the node, `HR` is the height of the right side.

`MaxH = (HL>HR)?HL:HR` uses the ternary operator (inline if expression) that says if `HL>HR` the value of this expression is `HL` otherwise `HR`.
That gives us our maximum height of the left and right sub-trees.

The return statement (`return (MaxH+1);`) adds the 1.

As stated in a comment it would be preferable to omit:

```
int HL,HR, MaxH;
```

And write

```
int HL = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Left); 
int HR = PostOrderGetHeight(BT->Right); 
int MaxH = (HL>HR)?HL:HR;
```

Before C99 (the 1999 standard) you were required to declare all variables at the start of the function. That gave the compiler an easy ride determine how much stack was required.

But it should not be preferred style unless shackled to a compiler that imposes the rule (not even all 20th century compilers did).

It's less readable and reduce safety by risking the use of uninitialized data such as in blocks it's not used in.

Slightly more obscurely it could also stop the compiler seeing opportunities to optimize the stack layout.

But in short I wonder if this code was written for a old-school compiler or by an old-timer. I don't apologise to calling anyone an old-timer. I wrote C code on those compilers. It's not an insult.

The definition of `BinTree` isn't provided but it must be similar to:

```
typedef struct BinTree_tag;

typedef struct {
    struct BinTree_tag *Left;
    struct BinTree_tag *Right;
} *BinTree ;
```