# Is there a reason to create the string variable before input?

Tags: java

Newly learning java and for input, we did

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;
System.out.println("What is your  name?");
name = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(name);
```

However, I found that

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(name);
```

works the same. Is this being taught to me in the bigger form because it's more generally used/is clearer or am I just being taught the bigger form since I'm a beginner to avoid too much confusion? (Basically, are there any reasons why people would use the expanded version rather than the condensed version?)

Comment: You cannot define variable two times. Also you are missing a semicolon I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, it's the same thing. It is more useful though when used in the context of variable scoping.

Creating a reference variable before initializing it with a value is the preferred way while using code blocks, so that the reference can also be used outside of the block. Check out this example:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++) {
    sum += idx;
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score 9):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/288479

-> It seems that in some old C-Standards you had to declare all variables in the beginning of a method. So I think they are just adhering to this when teaching it like this, but nowadays there is no real reason for this.

Answer (score 4):

Your correct extended version should be

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;
System.out.println("What is your  name?");
name = scan.nextLine(); // no need of String keyword here
System.out.println(name);
```

And why someone would prefer it?

Consider a method definition, May be something like below,

```
public AccountDetails getDetails(Person person){
   Address address;
   AccountInfo accountInfo;
   address = person.getAddresses();
   accountInfo = getDetailsOfAccount();

.......many more lines
   return accountDetails;
}
```

So from the above code, declaring all the variables at the top of the method with proper naming conventions is just helping you out upfront like a sign barrier on the road ahead, that what the method is dealing with.

Other than that, you can follow any version of the code, both are equally same.